# Как достать время начала события?

Tags: jquery, дата

Нужно взять время начала события и записать в переменную,
пробовал так:

```
<div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-30" data-time-start="August 30, 2020 19:00">

$(this).data("time-start"))
```

но получаю ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы использовали прям такое же написание как тут:

```
$(this).data("time-start"))
```

То - да, будет ошибка **`SyntaxError: unexpected token: ')'`**, из-за лишней скобки в конце.

```js
$(this).data("time-start"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-30" data-time-start="August 30, 2020 19:00">
```

Если её убрать, то всё будет хорошо.

P.s. советую использовать вместо `.data('name')` - `.attr('data-name')`.
Отличие [.data()](http://jquerybook.ru/api/.data()-fn47.html) от [.attr()](http://jquerybook.ru/api/.attr()-fn18.html).

```js
let data = $('.cell').data("time-start");
console.info(data);

//

let attr = $('.cell').attr("data-time-start");
console.info(attr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-30" data-time-start="August 30, 2020 19:00">
```

Comment: Спасибо (скобку не заметил)